# Use xargs and kill in script with optional signal

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting, kill, xargs

A script for terminating a server on a certain port:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

PORT="$1"
SIGNAL="$2"

if [ "${SIGNAL}" != "" ]; then SIGNAL=" -${SIGNAL}"; fi

lsof -i:"${PORT}" |\
  grep -e "localhost:${PORT}" -e TCP -e LISTEN |\
  tr -s ' ' |\
  cut -d' ' -f2 |\
  tee /dev/tty |\
  xargs --no-run-if-empty kill "$SIGNAL"
```

Works: `killbyport 4242`

But if I want to do a `kill -9` I'd do: `killbyport 4242 9`,
and that errors:

```
kill: (-9): No such process
```

*The `xargs` and `kill` aren't cooperating – how do I fix it?*

(PS: I want to fix this script, rather than change it to something else. It's almost working.)

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks. Note shellcheck gives "No issues detected!" :)

Comment: You do not need to escape the newline after the pipe character. IMHO it is best to avoid escaping newline when possible.

Comment: @pabouk Interesting, why do you suggest not to escape newlines?

Comment: Backslash used for line continuation has multiple problems: * You have to be careful that the backslash is not followed by a whitespace (invisible in most editors by default) or any other character. * You cannot add a comment to such a line. --- See for example this answer for Python (almost the same situation as in a shell): https://stackoverflow.com/a/61933/320437

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you’re explicitly adding a space to `SIGNAL`:

```
SIGNAL=" -${SIGNAL}"
```

and then referencing it in quotes:

```
kill "$SIGNAL"
```

Since `kill` is seeing an argument that *doesn’t* begin with dash
(because it begins with space, and then dash),
it isn’t seen as an option,
but as an ordinary argument — in this case, a PID. 
A quick fix is to ***not*** add the space to `SIGNAL`:

```
SIGNAL="-${SIGNAL}"
```

---

But it doesn’t make sense that this is working when `SIGNAL` is null. 
See [But what if …?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286350/23408). 
The first example (`ignorecase`) almost exactly matches your situation.

Comment: Your link led me to the answer, thanks. I added my fix below.

Answer (score 3):

@G-Man's answer led me in the right direction. For completeness, the fix is to use this instead:

```bsh
xargs --no-run-if-empty kill ${SIGNAL:+"-$SIGNAL"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of this is to run the command `kill " -9"` ... which is wrong.  Kill will interpret `" -9"` as a pid instead of `"-9"` which would be signal 9.

You are being too clever with your quoting.

Comment: isn't it the leading whitespace that's the real problem here, rather than the quoting?

Comment: @steeldriver: It's both.  Adding the space is an error, but, if `$2` was a valid non-negative integer, `kill $SIGNAL` (without quotes) would have worked (but for the wrong reason).

Comment: Without the quotes, the extra space is stripped.  With the quotes, the kill works, but doesn't use the specified signal because it thinks it is a pid that it can't find.

Comment: I've never been accused of being too clever... thanks! ;)